# GCC optimizations based on integer overflow

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-optimization, integer-overflow

Recently I had a discussion about someone who wanted to check for signed int overflow like this `if (A + B < 2 * max(A, B))`. Lets ignore for a second that the logic itself is wrong and discuss signed integer overflow in context of C/C++. (Which I believe fully inherits this part of standard from C).

What kinds of check that need signed integer overflow will be optimized away by current-ish GCC and which won't?

**Since the original text wasn't all that well formulated and apparently controversial I decided to change the question somewhat, but leave the original text below.**

*All examples used below were tested gcc version `4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)` and compiled using `-O3`*

Namely, it is undefined and GCC infamously uses this to perform some branch simplifications. The first example of this that comes to mind is

```
int i = 1;
while (i > 0){
    i *= 2;
}
```

which produces an infinite loop. Another case where this kind of optimalization kicks in is

```
if (A + 2 < A){
    /* Handle potential overflow */
}
```

where, assuming `A` is signed integral type, the overflow branch gets completely removed.

Even more interestingly, some cases of easily *provable* integer overflow, are left untouched, such as

```
if (INT_MAX + 1 < 0){
    /* You wouldn't write this explicitly, but after static analysis the program
       could be shown to contain something like this. */
}
```

which triggers the branch that you would expect with two's complement representation. Similarly, this code leaves the conditional branches intact

```
int C = abs(A);
if (A + C < 0){
    /* For this to be hit, overflow or underflow had to happen. */
}
```

Now for the question, is there a pattern that looks roughly like `if (A + B < C)` or `if (A + B < c)`, that will be optimized away? When I was googling around before writing this, it seemed like the last snippet should be optimized away, but I cannot reproduce this kind of error in an overflow check that doesn't operate with constant explicitly.

Comment: Your last example is much more complex than the other ones. It requires tracking a dependency between A and C through a function call, and a "mathematical understanding" of that function on top of what's already required for the other ones.

Comment: I don't really understand what exactly it is that you're asking for. "looks roughly like this" is a little vague

Comment: The thing is, as it is undefined behavior, any answer would be valid.

Comment: It's not "infamous" if it takes a malicious user to trigger the behaviour. If anything, it's an *encouragement* to write correct code and not rely on hacks.

Comment: @harold Large letter is supposed to be stand in for a variable, small letter for a constant.

Comment: @KerrekSB I would say it is infamous, because trying to check for overflow to prevent said malicious user from messing up things, gets optimised away in the name of making the code go faster. Honestly I think this whole part of the standard is a huge mess (which could be prevented by making it implementation defined instead of undefined).

Comment: @Xarn It's not infamous; it's doing exactly what the authors of the standard expected and wanted.  One of the main reasons for undefined behavior _is_ to allow the compiler to make some assumptions when optimizing.  What's infamous is that there are programmers who actually expect such things to work.  Overflow checking is normally written _before_ the operation.

Comment: It *is* infamous (arguing that it's correct doesn't make it not infamous), and while the standard allows it I strongly doubt it is what the authors intended. It's far more likely they merely intended to give leeway in how overflow occurs (saturate, trap, set a poison bit on the result, wrap in a different manner) than that they actually specifically intended for after-the-fact overflow checks to be ignored.

Comment: @JamesKanze Given some completely insane UB that is in the standard, I have some trouble with taking that at face value. (That this kind of optimization was intended.) In reality I think the committee felt lazy and just threw lots of things that could've been unspecified or implementation defined into undefined and called it quits. (I cannot explain things like unmatched `"` or `'` in the source code invoking UB in any other way)

Comment: @Xarn All I can say is that you're wrong.  There was, in fact, a great deal of opposition to defining the behavior in the case of unsigned types; the defined behavior has significant run-time cost on some architectures.  And some architectures do (or at least did) trap on overflow, which was also an important reason for making this undefined behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze: but AFAIK trap on overflow and saturating arithmethics happen mostly on signed types, and the runtime cost for unsigned types is mostly restricted to architectures with no native unsigned type, right?

Comment: @ninjalj Partially.  It's mainly a problem for machines which don't use 2's complement.  There are still a few (at least one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many compilers will replace expressions involving signed integers or pointers with "false", like

```
a + 1 < a // signed integer a
p + 1 < p // Pointer p
```

when the expression can only be true in the case of undefined behaviour. On the other hand, that allows

```
for (char* q = p; q < p + 2; ++q) ...
```

to be inlined, substituting q = p and q = p + 1, without any check, so that's a good thing.

```
if (A + abs (A) < 0)
```

is probably too complicated for many compilers. Note that for unsigned integers there is no undefined behaviour. As a consequence, loops using unsigned 32 bit integers with 64 bit pointers tend to be slower than necessary because the wraparound behaviour must be taken into account. For unsigned 32 bit integer and 64 bit pointers, it is possible that

```
&p [i] > &p [i+1]
```

without undefined behaviour (not with 64 bit integers or 32 bit pointers).

Comment: Not possible for pointers. Pointer arithmetic is undefined outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @R..: One could have an array whose size was too big to fit into a `uint32_t`, in which case the indicated expression would not entail any UB.

Answer (score 1):

If I may paraphrase your question, I believe that are asking something like this.

Does there exist a compiler that optimises signed integer expressions so aggressively that it is prepared to undertake detailed analysis of certain categories of such expressions in order to determine that a dependent condition is true (or false) throughout the `range of representable values for the type` of the result of the expression, and by those means delete the conditional test?

The compiler you offer is a particular version of GCC, and the expressions you offer fall into a narrow range, but I assume that you would also be interested to learn of another compiler or closely-related expressions.

The answer is right now I'm not aware of one, but it could be only a matter of time.

Existing compilers perform premature evaluation of expressions that contain constants or certain recognisable patterns, and if during this evaluation they encounter undefined behaviour will ordinarily avoid optimising the expression. They are not obliged to do so.

Data flow analysis is CPU and memory intensive and tends to be used where there are large benefits to be had. Eventually the C++ standard will stop changing (so much) and the compiler writers will have time on their hands. We're still a bit short of the day when a compiler reads a prime number sieve program and optimises it into a single print statement, but it will come.

The main point of my answer is to point out that this is actually a question about compiler technology and has very little to do with the C++ standard. Perhaps you should ask the GCC group directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the actual question was somewhat different (after thinking it through I formulated it properly in the OP).

Comment: Seems like the same question, except you limit it to GCC only. My answer (finally para) is even more correct.